# Run consecutive Commands Linux with java runtime exec

Tags: java, linux, runtime

I need to run two commands Linux using java code like this:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
          
           
            Process  pr=rt.exec("su - test");
            String line=null;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
          
            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                
                System.out.println(line);
            }
           pr = rt.exec("whoami");
             input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

             line=null;

            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
            }               
            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);              
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The problem is the output of the second command ("whoami") doesn't display the current user which used on the first command ("su - test")!
Is there any problem on this code please?

Comment: The try statement is missing. Please always post a runnable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [Javadoc for Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29):

> Executes the specified string command **in a separate process**.

each time you execute a command via exec() it will be executed in a separate subprocess.  This also means that the effect of su ceases to exist immediately upon return, and that's why the `whoami` command will be executed in another subprocess, again using the user that initially launched the program.

```
su test -c whoami
```

will give you the result you want.

Comment: and test in this context is suppossed to be the user account name? Can you clarify this please!

Answer (score 7):

In the general case, you need to run the commands in a shell.  Something like this:

```
    Process  pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /tmp ; ls"});
```

But in this case that's not going to work, because `su` is itself creating an interactive subshell.  You can do this though:

```
    Process  pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "whoami", "-", "test"});
```

or

```
    Process  pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"su", "test", "-c", "whoami"});
```

Another alternative is to use `sudo` instead of `su`; e.g.

```
    Process  pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"sudo", "-u", "test", "whoami"});
```

---

Note: while none of the above actually require this, it is a good idea to assemble the "command line" as an array of Strings, rather than getting `exec` to do the "parsing".  (The problem is that `exec`s splitter does not understand shell quoting.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple commands in a way the commands would execute in a subshell if need be see the response here

[How can I run multiple commands in just one cmd windows in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866381/how-can-i-run-multiple-commands-in-just-one-cmd-windows-in-java) (using ProcessBuilder to simulate a shell)