# What exactly can we store inside of string array in Process.exec()

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I can not find anywhere that specificity explain what can be store inside of `String[] cmdarray` of [`Process exec(String[] cmdarray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) method. I found some places `cmdarray` to store an array command or location of file and remote server name. So I wonder what exactly we can store inside of `String[] cmdarray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of the array is the command, such as `cmd`. The others are arguments. For example:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "echo", "This", "is", "an", "argument"});
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here `"/c"`, `"echo"`, `"This"`, `"is"`, `"an"`, and  `"argument"` are all arguments for the command `cmd`. The output is:

```
This is an argument
```

If you want to run multiple commands, you must use a double ampersand to indicate that another command is starting:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "echo", "This", "is", "an", "argument",
            "&&", "echo", "this", "command", "snuck", "in" });
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here each command is being sent to `cmd`. I'm not positive, but I believe you must start a new process to send commands elsewhere. The output is:

```
This is an argument 
this command snuck in
```

Read this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867097/5645656

Comment: Then, then can it be a list of commands such as "cmd", "cmd", "cmd" ?

Comment: Yes, if you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867097/5645656), you'll see that adding a double ampersand will mark the end of each command  the beginning of the next.

Comment: My pleasure! =)

Answer (score 2):

According to docs:

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.

Consider it as your command line interface inside JVM. It takes all process names that can be invoked using CMD. For eg: you can pass String `chromium` to `exec` in Ubuntu and you will notice that chromium is launched.