# How do you run terminal commands in a created android application on rooted emulator?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently creating an android application that will run some terminal commands. I am using a genymotion Nexus 5 (4.4.4) emulator that comes with root by default. However, to test some general commands I did the following:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"mkdir /sdcard/tmp1/"});
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"adb pull /sdcard/tmp3/new4.txt \"C:\\Users\\my_username\\Documents\\\""
```

When the "su" executes i get a message from an app named SuperUser saying I have have been given root privileges. However none of the other commands are executed. No tmp1 direcotry is made and I can't pull the new4.txt file, which I manually added to the emulator, to my documents folder.

Am I missing something in my path strings?

Comment: i can imagine each command runs on a different "session" so granted root access is not available for other commands, try to use `;` between commands, i think this way they will be executed with root permission?! ex `su ; mkdir /sdcard/tmp1/ ; ...`

Comment: What happens if you run the same commands in an `adb shell`?

Comment: Thank you all... You help me find what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the "su" executes i get a message from an app named SuperUser
>   saying I have have been given root privileges

So I guess you are running the code on the phone. In this case you are also running the third command (`adb pull`) on the phone, which you want to run on the host instead.

As [this answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17812887/638471) you are running consecutive commands in different sub-shells. So your first `su` will not matter in the second `exec`'s context. To execute a command with su see the [manual page of su](https://www.google.hu/search?hl=en&q=man%20su). A simple exeample is:

```
su - -c "whoami"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried "su", "-c", "mkdir /sdcard/tmp1/" all three strings inside the exec() together but the tmp1 folder was never created. @vbence

Comment: Make sure `/sdcard` is actually mounted in `rw` mode. You can open an `adb shell` on the host and run the `mount` command to check the mounted filesystems (and their modes).

Comment: @Corn It would be also useful if you saw the output of the commands. Consult: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150/638471